# Flexible workflow with tabular-based content

Tags: tables, tabbing, workflow

A language-related project I'm working on involves lots of vocabulary lists. (About two thousand words in total.) Not only that I haven't made up my mind as to how to present the lists, it is possible that there will be more than one version of it. (Say one for A4 paper, and one for tablet-size e-books, or maybe for phones.)

What workflow options do I have to gain maximum flexibility? I would think what I am asking is not realistic, but ultimately, I would like to have the ability to store the words (with respective translations) in a file, and be able to call them into a predefined tabbing or tabular environment. (For example, calling the first ten words to a tabbing, or alternatively to a tabular environment.) (Further, what would be the suggested method to store the words in an external file with maximum flexibility? (For example, for a given Arabic word I may enter an English translation and a German translation and later call either or both of them.))

Here is a VMWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=32pc,%
    paperheight=48pc,%
    margin=6pc,%
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabluatex}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{2cm}\=\hspace*{3cm}\= \kill
\arb{kataba} \> he wrote\\
\arb{fata.ha} \> he opened\\
\arb{jalasa} \> he sat\\
\arb{zahaba} \> he went\\
\arb{.daraba} \> he hit\\
\arb{kasara} \> he broke
\end{tabbing}    

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\arb{kataba}  & he wrote & \arb{fata.ha} & he opened \\
\arb{jalasa}  & he sat   & \arb{zahaba}  & he went   \\
\arb{.daraba} & he hit   & \arb{kasara}  & he broke 
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest to define a data-model with some commands that store your vocabs and some meta-data (shouldn't be a problem as you use LuaLaTeX. This way you have data to operate on which you can later do by programming (either Lua or TeX). That way you are flexible to define the output later on.

Comment: Did you look at packages such as `odsfile` or `datatool`?